# Silently Installing the Windows Genuine Advantage Tool

Tags: windows-update, activation, silent

I need to be able to silently download and install Windows Genuine Advantage. Where can I download it and What is the command line for silent installation?

I am surprised it's so hard to find this information. I need to install Microsoft Software that requires genuine Advantage to be installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure it is really all that hard. Just typing *"wga"* as the search keyword in the [Microsoft Download Center](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/default.aspx) site search would have sufficed to find this link:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=20888

The silent / unattended installation procedure is largely uniform for all hotfixes - just use the `/quiet /passive /norestart` parameter set for the [extracted version of the hotfix setup](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/unattendedapps.php#WGAInstall).